# Ubuntu 20.04 download link

Tags: downloads

I am trying to download ubuntu 20.04 LTS .But here there is a download link to download only ubuntu 22.04 LTS. So where will be the download file for Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Comment: The answers below tell you where to go, but not how they knew to go there...  FYI, the download page _does_ have an OTHER WAYS TO DOWNLOAD section at the bottom, which mentions that "You can also find [older releases](https://releases.ubuntu.com/)."

Comment: I just googled it

Answer (score 9):

Past releases are avaliable for download [here](https://releases.ubuntu.com/). That includes all the way back to 14.04. Click the one you want, and then select "Desktop image" if you want normal Ubuntu, or "Server install image" if you prefer no pre-installed GUI. Other files, including checksums and Bittorrent versions of the ISOs are further down the per-release page.

Releases prior to 14.04 can be downloaded from [this page](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)*.

*Downloading (and running) EOL/EoSS can (and usually does) have security implications. That said, I will not discuss the risks of downloading EOL/EoSS releases here other that to say I do not suggest it, and that those releases are off-topic on Ask Ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

The older versions of Ubuntu are indeed not availible via the standard download page, so you have to search the release archive. For the newest iteration of 20.04 LTS, use this page: https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/. For other releases, make the number at the end the release number and it will redirect you to the download page.

I will warn you though, old releases may have security issues that are fixed in newer releases. This shouldn't be a problem for 20.04 though, since it's still supported.